# IE 8,9 vs CSS3 incompatibility

Tags: css, internet-explorer, scroll

I might be asking too much, but I was wondering if someone could help me with the css for this site: http://parkoura.tk/a/sandbox/

I see a lot things that are dissimilar with regards to gow IE renders the page. I realize why the @font-face is not working.

Main concerns are the double scroll bars on the right of the page (content.css and master.css), as well as the way the arrows for the central navigation are displayed, and the list at the bottom of the central column.

Here are screen shots with the problems highlighted:

[image]

Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to [SO], please read the [faq].

Comment: wow.. an invalid doctype was to blame for all this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting rid of your overflow properties in the Div with ID="container". I also have a feeling that having your arrows sitting in a margin might be a problem. Hopefully that works.

Comment: oh thanks! I really love your suggestion about the div sitting in the margin. about the container div though, it doesnt fill the screen with color that way but yes, it does get rid of the scroll bars.

Answer (score 2):

First I would suggest including the Modernizr library:
http://modernizr.com/

Hopefully this solves most, if not all, of your compatibility issues. Please post any remaining you issues have that Modernizr doesn't solve.

Comment: You should be using the HTML5 doctype.